# How do I give a keyframed object a bit of vibration/shaking when it's at the destination point?

Tags: objects, armature, physics, transforms, keyframes

I made a robot with moving parts on it's body but when the parts move from the starting point to the ending point, I wanna give it some vibration like it moved with a certain force. How can I do this?

edit:
In the picture below u see a dummy wheel keyframed going to the left. But when it snaps in place on the stop point I want it to shake a bit, a bit of knockback, like it moved that way with a force but suddenly stopped.

edit2:
Look at youtube video I added below. The rotorblades are spinning (moving) with a certain force but when they snap in place, it keeps shaking for a split second, that's what I need.

[rotorblades snapping link](https://youtu.be/Ixhmcs5i_Oo)

[image]

Comment: hello, you can add some noise in the Graph Editor, but maybe be a bit more precise on what you want with some pictures or animated gif?

Comment: I added a picture with some explanation, I hope u understand

Comment: for this kind of simple animation I think it's not even worth to do it with noise, you can simply create keyframes that will give the effect you want, what kind of difficulty have you met?

Comment: This was just a quick example I made up haha. I am creating an animation where a truck transforms into the robot I made. I do this by folding the robot inside the truck, and make truck parts dissapear while the robot parts are coming out in the upwards motion. But when tires, doors, etc... from the front of the truck, snap on the back of the robots leg, chest, etc I wanna add that vibration, don't know how though.

Comment: have you checked the noise in the Graph Editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to Chris' answer, you can use a *Noise* modifier in the *Graph Editor*. Create your animation, open the *Graph Editor*, select the bone (or object), select the track where you want the vibration to happen, for example here the *Z Rotation* track, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide the others, and in the *N* panel, on the right of the *Graph Editor* window, create a *Modifiers > Modifier > Noise*. Now if you click on the *Restrict Frame Range* you can decide in what range of frames the vibration will happen. Here is what it can give:

[image]

Another solution, if you select your track, select the vertex or vertices where you want the effect to begin and press <kbd>T</kbd> (or header menu > *Key > Interpolation Mode*) you can create a *Dynamic Effects* like *Bounce* or *Elastic* (the settings are in the *FCurve* tab):

[image]

If these solutions are not satisfying I guess you need to do it manually...

Comment: Yes! The dynamic effects is what I'm looking for, the little bounce thing. Thanks!!

Comment: ok you can change the settings to a certain extent as you see on the right panel

Answer (score 0):

One other alternative for anyone looking to achieve an effect like this is to put the animation in an *NLA Strip* and use the **Noise** *NLA Modifier*.

This is especially helpful if you have *a lot* of channels (like a rigged character shivering); nevertheless, this should also work handily for OP's example.