# Adding a "modifier" to the mapping node / Animating World

Tags: animation, modifiers, animation-nodes

Is there a way to add a modifier (e.g. noise) to World animation? I want to animate a rotation in a mapping node and I want to add a little shake to it. How can I do it?

Comment: Yes see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209512/how-do-i-give-a-keyframed-object-a-bit-of-vibration-shaking-when-its-at-the-des/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107102/how-to-add-bumpiness-to-a-car-roller-coaster-motion

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a keyframe on the *Mapping* location values of the *World* material, keep the *Mapping* node selected, open the *Graph Editor*, open its *N* panel, click on the *Modifiers* tab, add the *Noise* modifier, tweak the parameters:

[image]